# Многоязычность программы в Delphi

Tags: delphi, локализация

Нужно, что бы программа поддерживала различные языки. Поискав в интернете нашёл пример кода:

```
procedure TForm1.ChangeLang(LangSection: string);
var
i: Integer;
LangIniFile: TIniFile;
ProgramPath: string;
begin
  if ComponentCount <> 0 then
  begin
    ProgramPath := ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName);
    if ProgramPath[Length(ProgramPath)] <> '\' then
      ProgramPath := ProgramPath + '\';
    LangIniFile:=TIniFile.Create(ProgramPath+'lang.ini');
    Caption:=LangIniFile.ReadString(LangSection,name,Caption);
    for i:=1 to ComponentCount do
    begin
      if Components[i-1].ClassType = TButton then
        (Components[i-1] as TButton).Caption := LangIniFile.ReadString(LangSection,
        name+Components[i-1].name, (Components[i-1] as TButton).Caption);

    end;
    LangIniFile.Free;
  end;
end;
```

две кнопки, которые должны были бы его запускать

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form1.ChangeLang('ENGLISH');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Form1.ChangeLang('RUSSIAN');
```

сам ini файл выглядит так:

```
[RUSSIAN]
Form1Button1=Кнопка

[ENGLISH] 
Form1Button1=Button
```

Компиляция проходит успешно, но никакого эффекта за этим не следует. Если можно, помогите с этим кодом, или подкиньте подходящую литературу, где это доступно(для чайников) описывается.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону dxGetText (например, https://habrahabr.ru/post/264693/)

Comment: Если кнопка на панели, то надо её на панели искать (цикл по компонентам панели), кстати. Лучше попробовать сделать тестовую функцию. Типа GetButtonCaption в параметрах ну и посмотреть какие имена компонентов находятся в цикле, сделать их вывод на экран... То есть, возможно 1) не читается из ини файла строка, 2) не находится компонент

Comment: какая версия delphi то? там где то во времена ХЕ2 добавили поддержку локализаций

Comment: @AlbertFomin вы не правы. В `Components` перечислены компоненты, для которых форма явялется владельцем (`owner`). К тому, где расположен компонент, на панели или нет, (т..е `parent`) это не относится. Владельцем форма будет являться для всего что есть на форме, пока вы не указали владельца явно при динамическом создании компонента. Владение определяет лишь время жизни созданных компонентов и возлагает на владельца отвественность за их освобождение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
procedure TForm1.ChangeLang(aSection: string);
var
  i: integer;
  langIniFile: TIniFile;
  iniFileName: string;
begin
  if ComponentCount > 0 then
  begin
    iniFileName := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'lang.ini';
    if not FileExists(iniFileName) then
      ShowMessage('Could not find file ' + iniFileName);
    langIniFile := TIniFile.Create(iniFileName);
    try
      if not langIniFile.SectionExists(aSection) then
        ShowMessage('Could not find section ' + aSection);

      Caption := langIniFile.ReadString(aSection, Name, Caption);
      for i := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do
      begin
        if Components[i] is TButton then
          (Components[i] as TButton).Caption := langIniFile.ReadString(
            aSection,
            Name + Components[i].Name, 
            (Components[i] as TButton).Caption
          );
      end;
    finally
      langIniFile.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Не используйте глобальную переменную `Form1` внутри методов класса `TForm1`.

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ChangeLang('ENGLISH');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ChangeLang('RUSSIAN');  
end;
```

Comment: предлагаете ваш ответ построчно с кодом из вопроса сравнивать? что изменилось-то можно ведь написать?

Comment: Не могли бы вы мне объяснить как работает ваш код?
Мне кажется, я напортачил в инишке.

Comment: @Temo4ka какая часть кода Вам непонятна? Вы его запустили? Какие-нибудь сообщения появились?

Comment: @Igor Да, при запуске всё хорошо. Когда нажимаю на одну из кнопок, то появляется ошибка "Could not find section RUSSIAN/ENGLISH". 
Моя инишка всё ещё выглядит так:

    [RUSSIAN]
Form1Button1=Кнопка

[ENGLISH]
Form1Button1=Button

Comment: значит, у Вас в коде есть вызов `ChangeLang('RUSSIAN/ENGLISH');`

Comment: Нет-нет, я хотел этим показать, что обе кнопки. Будь это RUSSIAN или ENGLISH действуют одинаково.  
Вызова два и они стоят так как у Вас указано 
    ChangeLang('RUSSIAN');

Comment: Удалите/переименуйте ini файл. Нажмите кнопку. Появилось сообщение "Could not find file ..."?

Comment: Да, "Could not find file ...\lang.ini"

Comment: @Igor скорее всего у него в папке `ini` файл написан с большой буквы а в коде с маленькой `'lang.ini'`. Стоит сменить или в коде или поправить названия файла.

Comment: @Insider В Windows названия файлов/папок - регистро-независимые.

Comment: @Temo4ka У Вас ini файл, случайно, не в юникоде? А Delphi какой версии?

Comment: @Igor Вы оказались совершенно правы! ini файл был в юникоде! Я совершенно не представляю как это получилось!
Спасибо Вам огромное, всё работает!

Answer (score 0):

1. встроенный в Delphi XE/DX компонент для локализиации работает, но ужасен.
2. коммерческий TsiLang тоже не идеален. работает намного лучше чем встроенный.
3. обсуждение данной темы http://www.sql.ru/forum/1210906-1/lokalizaciya-proekta-na-delphi-chto-posovetuete
4. есть (были) несколько open source проектов, для решения данного вопроса. к сожалению не могу найти сейчас